# Python csv.DictReader returning KeyError

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a script that reads/writes to a csv file depending on user input. Pretty much it simulates a password manager. However, when i tried to view it through the script using csv.DictReader, it returns KeyError.

The csv file was created as a blank and the data were inputted through the script itself.

```
import csv

with open('Pass.csv') as csv_file:

    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for lines in csv_reader:
        print(f'{row["application"]} | {row["ID"]} | {row["password"]}')
```

I've noticed that if i change the

```
print(f'{row["application"]} | {row["ID"]} | {row["password"]}')
```

to

```
print(lines)
```

it returns the following output:

```
OrderedDict([(None, ['application', 'ID', 'password'])])
OrderedDict([(None, ['asd', 'dsa', 'asd'])])
```

So my question is why does it return None in the first place which seems to be the issue that caused the KeyError to arise.

In the link is the csv file i've used to test the DictReader:
http://www.filedropper.com/pass_1

Comment: could you edit the question down to something more easily reproducible?  e.g. an example input file and the few lines from `readPass` that demonstrate the issue

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I've edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your exact code and could not reproduce your error. After inputting two entries, I get:

```py
>>> readPass()
Application | ID | Password
ap1 | id1 | pw1
application | ID | password
ap2 | id2 | pw2
```

As you can see, the printing is working fine, but you do have a bug in that you are writing new headers with every entry to the CSV file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do realise the issue with repeating header which i've yet to fix. But for now i've included my sample file in the post. Perhaps you can take a look if that file will reproduce the KeyError through DictReader?

Comment: The example `Pass.csv` you linked to has a blank line at the start of the file. This blank line is being interpreted as the header of the CSV file, the `None` in your output. If you get rid of the blank line, you'll be able to parse the CSV.